# Download Images from FTP in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ftp, download

I have a list of images along with full path of FTP stored in my SQL SERVER.
Now I want to download that images from the web page, Suppose I have search criteria after that 50 images shows in my grid then once i hit the download images all the images download into my local computer.

Waiting for your valuable answers
thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perhaps use the [FTPWebRquest library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) in the .NET framework

Simple implementation can be found [here](http://aspalliance.com/1187_Building_a_Simple_FTP_Application_Using_C_20.3)

Answer (score 0):

General downloading code using the `WebClient` Class

```
using System.Net;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.DownloadData("FTP_URL");
}
```